# why are there 3 undesired characters in the beginning of the string in C language?

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a problem with this C program that reads the content of a file and copies it in a string then prints it.
when I allocate a string, it has always 3 strange characters in it, and I could solve that by putting '\0' at the beginning to like initialize it to an empty string, as shown in part 1 and 2.
But when it comes to reading the file, even with that technique the 3 characters won't go, like shown in part 3.

Anyone knows why those 3 chars are printed, knowing that if I copy the string into another file, they don't appear in it; and why do they still appear when i read the file ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define length 20

int main() { /////////PART 1

    char *T = (char*) malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char)) ;
    printf("%s\n", T); 

    strcat(T,  "hello") ;
    printf("%s\n", T); 

////////////////////////////////////PART 2  

    char *M = (char*) malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char)) ; M[0] = '\0' ;
    printf("%s\n", M);

    strcat(M,  "hello") ;
    printf("%s\n", M); 

////////////////////////////////////PART 3 

    FILE *fil = fopen("test.txt", "r") ;
    char *S = (char*) malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char)) ; S[0] = '\0' ;


    fread(S, sizeof(char), length, fil); 
    S[length] = '\0' ;

    printf("%s\n", S) ;
    fclose(fil) ;
}
```

Comment: Never assume anything about the contents of memory returned by `malloc`.

Comment: If you want initialize memory use calloc: `char *t = calloc(length+1, 1)`. If `t` is then not NULL (do check that, always), the memory it points to will be set to all zeroes.

Comment: `strcat(T,  "hello") ;` you can't do this before initializing `T`. You need to do as in your other examples, append a manual null terminator to index 0 before calling `strcpy`

Comment: If it only happens in part 3, after reading that particular file (you say that it doesn't happen if you copy the text to another file), the file might be saved in character coding UTF-8 BOM. This has a 3 character signature. That means that those three characters are part of the file and not an error of malloc.

Comment: Try doing `printf(%x %x %x\n", S[0], S[1], S[2]);`.  If you get `ef bb bf`, it's the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 2):

Could the 3 characters be `ï»¿` or `´╗┐`? It is common to prepend a Byte Order Mark at the beginning of unicode text files. The BOM is the magic value 0xfeff.

On a UTF-8 encoded files it comes as 3 bytes `"\xef\xbb\xbf"`, on a UTF-16 Little Endian, it is the 2 bytes `"\xff\xfe"` and on a UTF-16 Big Endian, it is the 2 bytes `"\xfe\xff"`.

If you are reading a file that contains a BOM, having those special characters is normal.